# Python: Compare every single row in a column to all other entries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that contains strings like this:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["hello, this is a test. we want to remove entries, where the text is similar to other texts",
                           "hello, this is a test. we want to remove entries, where the text is similar to other texts because",
                           "where are you going",
                           "i'm going to the zoo to pet the animals",
                           "where are you going jane",
                           "where are you going asd"]})
```

I want to remove the rows where the sentence is **similar** to a previous row. "Similar" in this context means that they share 75% of the same words.

Here is how I am currently doing it (using a for-loop):

```
def find_duplicates(df):
    df = df.str.split().apply(set)
    ls_duplicates = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        doc_i = df.iloc[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
            doc_j = df.iloc[j]
            score = len(doc_i.intersection(doc_j)) / len(doc_j)
            if score > 0.7:
                ls_duplicates.append(j)
    return ls_duplicates

d.iloc[find_duplicates(d['text'])]
```

This gives the desired output:

```
                                                text
1  hello, this is a test. we want to remove entri...
4                           where are you going jane
5                            where are you going asd
5                            where are you going asd
```

Now, this runs very slow when my dataframe is large (>10k rows). Is there a way to optimize the for-loop?

Comment: do the words need to be in the same order to be considered similar? For example: "I am a cat" and "A cat I am" would those be a 100% or 0% match?

Comment: That would be a 100% match

Comment: Alright give me a few minutes. I think I have a good way for you

Comment: How do you want to handle strings of different length? for example: "hi how are you" and "hi you". When comparing the first to the second I would have 100% of the words covered but it wouldn't have the same number of words. How do you want to treat this?

Comment: oh I just realized it is only to the previous row

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["hello, this is a test. we want to remove entries, where the text is similar to other texts",
                           "hello, this is a test. we want to remove entries, where the text is similar to other texts because",
                           "where are you going",
                           "i'm going to the zoo to pet the animals",
                           "where are you going jane",
                           "where are you going asd"]})


df['prev_text'] = df.text.shift(-1)
df.fillna('NA', inplace=True)

def find_duplicates(x):
    text = set(x.text.split())
    prev_text = set(x.prev_text.split())

    return len(text.intersection(prev_text))/len(prev_text)

df['score'] = df.apply(find_duplicates, axis=1)

print(df)

print(df[df.score < 0.7].text)
```

Tested that it is 65% faster.

Comment: This answer is great.

Comment: This is a nice answer - but why only shift by 1? I guess we have to switch by integers from 1 to the length of the array?

Comment: I think shifting by negative one, -1, will give you the previous row.